# Biggest value of (not all) dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

What's the best way to get the biggest value of only the keys **x**, **y**, **w** and **z** in the dictionary above using Python?

`my_dict = {"a":0, "b":5, "c":3, "x":4, "y":3, "w":2, "z": 1}`

Thanks

Comment: I could use a for loop to get the keys and compare them with item in a list but I know it isn't the best way in terms of performance and clean code.

Comment: Please use the edit button to post your code in your question so we can start from there.

Comment: Your usage of strings is rather confusing. Please double-check if you meant mixing ints and strings the way you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
my_dict = {"a":0, "b":5, "c":3, "x":4, "y":3, "w":2, "z": 1}
print(max(my_dict[i] for i in ["x", "y", "w", "z"]))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: I was too slow x)

Comment: OP just edited the input. now your answer is too complex... also, a bit of explanation doesn't hurt.

Comment: To repeat what Jean is saying, You don't need to have list brackets. `max(my_dict[i] for i in ["x", "y", "w", "z"])` is fine. You can even use tuples since it's immutable anyways. `max(my_dict[i] for i in ("x", "y", "w", "z"))`

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx Thank you for the clarification. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a temporary dictionary to hold your values, then search in this dictionary for the value you want.

```
my_dict = {"a":0,"b":5,"c":3,"x":4, "y":3, "w":2, "z": 1}
newdict = {key:my_dict[key] for key in ['x', 'y','w','z']}
print(newdict[max(newdict, key=newdict.get)])
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to generate a list of tuples with keys and items of target elements

```
tmp_tpl =  [(i, my_dict[i]) for i in ["x", "y", "z", "w"]]
```

And then take the `max` of that:

```
out = max(tmp_tpl, key= lambda x:x[1])
```

Note that this will print a tuple of key and item which lets you identify which key did the maximum item correspond to.